# Looking at a PCB is it possible to ascertain the number of layers it has?

Tags: hardware, pcb

Is there a way to ascertain - without special equipment (other than what a "layman electronics enthusiast" may have around) - how many layers a PCB has?

Is there some sort of marking or a technique to deduce it?

Only other requirement: it should not damage the PCB.

This question is loosely related to [that one](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1460/245), but hardly a duplicate.